# Get location of touch at anytime in Spritekit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am creating a game where you have to draw a line while a camera moves to the side indefinitely. I originally create this drawing by using the touchMoved function to draw whenever the player moves their finger. The issue is that if they hold their finger in one location while the camera moves to the side, it will not draw it until there has been a touchMoved call. My solution is putting the drawing part into the update function, so if finger is held down, I will call the drawing function. How am I able to get the location of a touch that is **not** touchBegin, touchEnd, or touchMoved?

Comment: You can't,  you need to use a flag variable in those three functions,  when the touchBegins, you set your flag to true, when your touch ends, set it to false.  if your flag is true, then draw

Comment: I do that, but it needs to location of the touch every update when that flag is true. @Knight0fDragon

Comment: you save the touch position when you move

Comment: Based on the camera? @Knight0fDragon

Comment: you convert to the camera when you need it